# Why does the titanium go to the tungsten filament in the crystal bar process?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis, process-chemistry

I've tried to read a report by the US atomic energy commission [[1](https://doi.org/10.2172/4393936)], but couldn't really find the answer, or maybe I missed it.

Why is the gaseous titanium deposited on the tungsten wire/filament during the van Arkel–de Boer process?

#### Reference

1. Petersen, A. W. *Preparation of Metallic Titanium by Film Boiling (Thesis)*; UCRL-2523, 4393936; United States, **1954**. DOI: [10.2172/4393936](https://doi.org/10.2172/4393936).

Comment: $\ce{Ti + 2I2 <=> TiI4}$ is an endothermic reaction.  In the chamber, temperatures are high enough that there is $\ce{TiI4}$, but the tungsten filament is so hot that $\ce{TiI4}$ decomposes again.  Or, to cite the [Dutch Wikipedia](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Arkel-de_Boerproces): forward reaction at $\pu{600 ^\circ{}C}$, backward reaction at $\pu{1200 ^\circ{}C}$ for a $\Delta{}H = \pu{−427 kJ/mol}$.  A bit like a halogen lamps, if you still have at your bicycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "gaseous titanium", do you mean "titanium tetraiodide ($\ce{TiI4}$) vapor"?

Van-Arkel De-Boer process is a purification process of titanium and zirconium. Basically, what happens is that the impure metal, let's say titanium is heated in iodine environment at a temperature of $\ce{250 ^\circ C}$ to form volatile titanium tetraiodide ($\ce{TiI4}$) vapor. The impurities are left behind, as they do not react with iodine. This vapor is then  passed over a hot tungsten filament at $\ce{1400 ^\circ C}$ for which the vapor gets decomposed and pure titanium is deposited on the filament and is removed. The iodine is reused. The overall reaction is:

$$\ce{Ti _{(impure)} + 2I2 ->[250 ^\circ C] TiI4 ->[1400 ^\circ C][W filament] Ti_{(pure)} + 2I2}$$

The thermodynamics of this reaction is discussed in Buttonwood's comment.

Comment: Except that Buttonwood stated it upside down (although the point is clear, that the dissociation is endothermic)